# when refactoring using extract method, should you extract into a new class or into the current class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, refactoring, extract

I've been using extract method to make the flow of my code easier to understand, but now I have a load of these methods just dumped at the bottom of my class file. I've thought about creating individual classes for the methods or groups of them but I'm just worrying if that would be adding unnecessary complexity. Any tips for doing this elegantly would be appreciated.

example - I know this is colossal and breaks several principles, I'm studying the SOLID principles vigorously right now but I have years of bad habits built up.

this is a custom GUI inspector for unity used for making cutscenes in my game.

```
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(Cutscene))]
public class CutsceneEditor: Editor
{
    GameObject parent;
    Cutscene cutscene;
    GameObject currentMarker = null;
    SerializedProperty startMarker, sequenceList;
    string[] actionOptions = {"Movement", "Poses"};
    float scrollbarOffset;
    GUIContent noLabel = new GUIContent();
    List<bool> foldouts;
    int currentFoldout;
    string hideText;

    void OnEnable() 
    {
        cutscene = (Cutscene)target;
        parent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PathUI");
        startMarker = serializedObject.FindProperty("startMarker");
        sequenceList = serializedObject.FindProperty("cutsceneSequences");   
        noLabel.text = "";
        foldouts = new List<bool>();
        //IsPathIsVisible();

        if (Application.isPlaying == false && (IsPathIsVisible() == true))
        {
            DrawCutscenePath(1);
        }

        foreach(SerializedProperty Cs in sequenceList)
        {
            foldouts.Add(false);
        }
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() 
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying == false)
        {
            DisplayCutsceneTabs();
        }
    }

    void DisplayCutsceneTabs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequenceList.arraySize; i ++)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.Space(5);
                var sequenceElement = sequenceList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                var actionMarker = serializedObject.FindProperty("actionMarker");
                var actionMarkerArrow = serializedObject.FindProperty("actionMarkerArrow");
                var startPoint = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("cutsceneStartPoint");
                var startRotation = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("cutsceneStartRotation");
                var cutsceneAction = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("cutsceneAction");
                var actionSelection = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("actionSelectionIndex");
                var timeToWait = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("timeToWait");
                var maxTimeToWait = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("maxTimeToWait");
                var voiceClip = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("voiceClip");
                var hasDialogue = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("hasDialogue");
                var voiceClipDelay = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("voiceClipDelay");
                var voiceClipVolume = sequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("voiceClipVolume");
            
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Start Point Object");
                    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Cutscene Markers");
                    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

                    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(startMarker, noLabel);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(actionMarker, noLabel);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(actionMarkerArrow, noLabel);
                    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                    EditorGUILayout.Space(10);

                    // set start position to start markers position
                    if (startMarker.objectReferenceValue != null)
                    {
                        GameObject startObject = startMarker.objectReferenceValue as GameObject;
                        startPoint.vector3Value = startObject.transform.position;
                        startRotation.quaternionValue = startObject.transform.rotation;
                    }
                    HandleButtons(0);
                    DrawBlackBox();
                    continue;
                }
                
                
                if (foldouts[i] = EditorGUILayout.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup(foldouts[i], "Cutscene Action " + "#" + " " + i))
                {
                    currentFoldout = i;
                    CloseAlmostAllFoldouts(i);

                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

                        actionSelection.intValue = EditorGUILayout.Popup(actionSelection.intValue, actionOptions, GUILayout.MaxWidth(100));
                        if (actionSelection.intValue == 0)
                        {
                            cutsceneAction.objectReferenceValue = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(cutsceneAction.objectReferenceValue, typeof(MovementAction), false) as MovementAction;
                        }
                        if (actionSelection.intValue == 1)
                        {
                            cutsceneAction.objectReferenceValue = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(cutsceneAction.objectReferenceValue, typeof(PoseAction), false) as PoseAction;
                        }
                        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
                        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

                        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                        
                        timeToWait.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider(timeToWait.floatValue, 0, maxTimeToWait.floatValue);
                        maxTimeToWait.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(maxTimeToWait.floatValue,  GUILayout.MaxWidth(25));

                        if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                        {
                            DrawCutscenePath(i);
                        }            
                        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                    }

                    scrollbarOffset = (sequenceList.arraySize < 8) ? 20 : 32;

                    hasDialogue.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("Show Voice Options", hasDialogue.boolValue);

                    if (hasDialogue.boolValue == true)
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(voiceClip);
                        voiceClipVolume.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Volume", voiceClipVolume.floatValue, 0, 2);
                        voiceClipDelay.floatValue = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Delay", voiceClipDelay.floatValue, 0, maxTimeToWait.floatValue);
                        
                        if (voiceClip.objectReferenceValue != null)
                        {
                            if (GUILayout.Button("Remove Voice Clip"))
                            {
                                voiceClip.objectReferenceValue = null;
                                voiceClipVolume.floatValue = 1;
                                voiceClipDelay.floatValue = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HandleButtons(i);
                    DrawBlackBox();        
                    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndFoldoutHeaderGroup();
                if (i == sequenceList.arraySize - 1)
                {
                    var DrawPathButtonArea = EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
                    EditorGUILayout.Space(40);
                    EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

                    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, DrawPathButtonArea.y, Screen.width, 20), (hideText != null)? hideText : "Hide Cutscene Tab"))
                    {
                        HideCutscenePath();
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    void HandleButtons(int i)
    {
        var tabEnd = EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, tabEnd.y + 15, 75, 20), "New Move"))
        {
            sequenceList.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            CutsceneSequenceDisplay.InitializeNewMove(sequenceList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i + 1));
            foldouts.Insert(i, false);
            if (i != 0)
            DrawCutscenePath(i);
        }
        if (i > 0)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - scrollbarOffset - 20, tabEnd.y + 15, 20, 20), "D"))
            {
                foldouts.Insert(i, false);
                sequenceList.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                DrawCutscenePath(i);
                CloseAlmostAllFoldouts(i);
            }
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - scrollbarOffset, tabEnd.y + 15, 20, 20), "X"))
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {          
                    foldouts.RemoveAt(i);
                    sequenceList.DeleteArrayElementAtIndex(i);   
                    DrawCutscenePath((i)=i != 1 ? i - 1 : i);          
                }
                else if (sequenceList.arraySize > 0)
                {
                    foldouts.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    sequenceList.DeleteArrayElementAtIndex(i + 1);
                }         
            }
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    void CloseAlmostAllFoldouts(int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < foldouts.Count; i++)
        {
            if(i != index)
            {
                foldouts[i] = false;  
            }
        }
    }

    void DrawCutscenePath(int index)
    {
        GameObject[] parents = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ParentUI");
       if (IsPathIsVisible() == true || parents.Length > -1) 
       {

            if (parents.Length != 0)
            {
                for(int i = index - 1; i < parents.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (parents[i].activeSelf == true)
                    {
                        DestroyImmediate(parents[i].gameObject);
                    }
                }
            }      
            for (int i = index; i < sequenceList.arraySize; i ++)
            {
                var thisSequenceElement = sequenceList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                var cutsceneAction = thisSequenceElement.FindPropertyRelative("cutsceneAction").objectReferenceValue;

                if (cutsceneAction is MovementAction)
                {
                    CutsceneSequenceDisplay.ProcessMovementPathing(i, sequenceList, serializedObject, ref currentMarker);
                }
                if (cutsceneAction is PoseAction)
                {
                    CutsceneSequenceDisplay.ProcessPosePathing(i, sequenceList, serializedObject, ref currentMarker);
                }
            }    
       }
    }

    bool IsPathIsVisible()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in parent.transform)
        {
            if (child.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void HideCutscenePath()
    {    
        if (parent != null)
        {
            bool isPathVisible = false;

            foreach (Transform child in parent.transform)
            {
                child.gameObject.SetActive(!child.gameObject.activeSelf);
                isPathVisible = child.gameObject.activeSelf;
            }
            hideText = (isPathVisible) ? "Hide Cutscene Path" : "Show Cutscene Path";
        }
            
    }

    void DrawBlackBox()
    {
        Color boxColor = new Color(0,0,0,0.2f);
        EditorGUILayout.Space(15); 
        var position = EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        EditorGUI.DrawRect(new Rect(0,position.y,Screen.width,20), boxColor);
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        EditorGUILayout.Space(20); 
    }

}

#endif
```

Comment: It would be good to give some example code. Both extracting as same class method and extracting the entire abstraction to separate class makes sense in different cases.

Comment: Okay, I put some code up there @blami I know that I'm probably breaking a lot of principles, I have a lot of bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

well, it...depends. As a general rule of thumb, try to minimize the number of private methods in a class, they're always a bad sign. Follow the Single Responsibility principle: a class should do one and one thing only.

Also, favor Composition over Inheritance: handling a long inheritance chain can get complex and lead to nasty bugs. Use Components to define the behavior of an object instead.

Anyways, if you post some example code we might be able to be more specific :)

Comment: Okay, this is the first time I've ever shared my code to be honest and it's kinda embarrassing, I'm self taught and have only recently started reading about SOLID principles / design patterns and refactoring, I know that there's a lot of I need to improve so any tips would also be appreciated.